# C# CheckBox Method logic wont manipulate

Tags: c#, visual-studio, checkbox, uwp, logic

I'm coding C# and trying to manipulate certain aspects if a user clicks the checkbox. Every time I try to build this simple method no errors but the logic doesn't work. How do I utilize IsChecked effectively and right?

```
 public void Function1() 
        {
            if (expBox.IsChecked == true)
            {
                TEST.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
            }
            else if(noobBox.IsChecked == true)
            {
                noobBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
            else if(expertBox.IsChecked == true)
            {
                expertBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            }
        }
```

Comment: What isn't working? Do you have expBox checked? If so, it won't ever reach any of the else ifs. Try changing the else ifs to their own if statements to see if you get the expected behavior.

Comment: It doesn't allow me to do anything when clicked. I've tried to get it to show text, make text disappear, etc. Making them all ifs still doesn't do anything, no errors but won't output what I want.

Comment: Can you tell more detail about where you call `Function1` method?

Comment: in my Public MainPage()

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing here, but it seems you didn't bind your Function1 to an change event.

Changes in your Xaml:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="expBox" Content="Expert CheckBox"
      Checked="Function1" Unchecked="Function1" />
```

Changes in your CodeBehind:

```
 public void Function1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) 
    {
 
        if (expBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            TEST.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        }
        else if(noobBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            noobBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
        else if(expertBox.IsChecked == true)
        {
            expertBlock.Visibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
        }
    }
```

This way your function1 will be called each time the "expBox" check state has been changed. Further more I would recommend to check how to accomplish all of that within Xaml.

Comment: Yeah that didn't work but broke everything. Bunch of 
Error CS0123 No overload for 'Function1' matches delegate

Comment: Are you setting the Function1 in your xaml.cs code ?

Comment: Yep. No errors just doesn't output.

Comment: Can you explain more clearly what effect you want to implement